# Counting the number of transactions for part of a day in SQL (hive)

Tags: sql, hive, sum, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have two tables that I am merging together and want to count the number of transactions before certain points. For example in the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (ID INT, time TIME);

INSERT INTO table1 
VALUES
(1, '11:30:00'),
(1, '14:30:00'),
(1, '18:00:00')
;

CREATE TABLE table2 (ID INT, txn_time TIME, txn_val INT);

INSERT INTO table2
VALUES
(1, '10:45:13', 1),
(1, '10:50:52', 2),
(1, '11:01:20', 4),
(1, '14:32:12', 2),
(1, '16:43:20', 5),
(1, '19:22:02', 3)
;
```

I want to count the number of transactions in table2 that come before each time in table one (accumulative). So for the above data I want the following table:

```
┌─────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ ID          │        time  │    txn count │
├─────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┤
│ 1           │     11:30:00 │            3 │
│ 1           │     14:30:00 │            3 │
│ 1           │     18:00:00 │            5 │
└─────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

The code I have at the moment is:

```
SELECT t1.ID,
t1.time,
sum(CASE WHEN t2.txn_time < t1.time THEN 1 END) over(PARTITION BY t1.time)
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.time
ORDER BY t1.time
```

But this gives the wrong numbers, so there is something I am missing. Do you know how to achieve this using partition by, or if there is a simpler method? Ultimately I will be wanting to do this for several days with the count resetting at the start of each day. It is also doing a many to many join, which becomes increasingly expensive for larger datasets, but I don't know how to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

You can `join` and aggregate:

```
select t1.id, t1.time, count(t2.id) as txn_count
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 
    on  t2.id = t1.id 
    and t2.txn_time <= t1.time
group by t1.id, t1.time
```

This is not optimized, as the same rows in `table2` end up joined multiple times as the `time` in `table1` increases. It might be more efficient to pre-compute ranges in `table1`, then to use window functions:

```
select t1.id, t1.time, 
    sum(count(t2.id)) over(partition by id order by time) as txn_count 
from (
    select t1.*, lag(t1.time) over(partition by id order by time) lag_time
    from table1 t1
) t1
left join table2 t2 
    on  t2.id = t1.id
    and t2.txn_time <= t1.time 
    and (t2.txn_time > t1.lag_time or t1.lag_time is null)
group by t1.id, t1.time
```

Comment: Just seen the edit and had figured out the same thing. I removed my last comment as I had just fixed before you updated. That answer does work now though, thanks.